# Remove n characters after certain character

Tags: python, regex, string

I have an string that looks something like this:

```
*45hello I'm a string *2jwith some *plweird things
```

I need to remove all the * and the 2 chars that follow those * to get this:

```
hello I'm a string with some weird things
```

Is there a practical way to do it without iterating over the string?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using regular expression:

```
import re
s = "*45hello I'm a string *2jwith some *plweird things"
s = re.sub(r'\*..', '', s)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex:

```
import re
regex = r"\*(.{2})"
test_str = "*45hello I'm a string *2jwith some *plweird things"
# You can manually specify the number of replacements by changing the 4th argument
result = re.sub(regex, '', test_str, 0)
```